# Mongo multiple JSON file insert error

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to insert multiple JSON documents into mongoDB with:

`for (i=0; 1<1000000; i++){ mongoimport -d test -c questions TWDS1E1.txt}`

TWDS1E1.txt is our JSON file held locally in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin`

But I am getting `Unexpected identifier` error!

I have also tried `db.collections.insert( TWDS1E1.txt )` but getting `TWDS1E1 is not defined error`

What am I doing wrong and how can I insert multiple documents for the shell?

Mant thanks

Comment: your file format is `.txt` not `.json`

Comment: @gypsyCoder thanks for the reply I've tried both .txt and .json file formats and still getting this error!?

Comment: you are trying to import same file for 1000000 times?

Comment: @gypsyCoder yes I want to populate the database to run some timing tests. Just can't seem to get the documents into mongo!?

Comment: i think, you are taking the wrong approach or your concept is wrong... 
`mongoimport -d test -c questions file.json` imports documents into specified collection... doing it for 1000000 times is meaningless

Comment: on the other hand `db.collections.insert()` expects a BSON document as parameter, as a result you are getting `TWDS1E1 is not defined error`

Comment: @gypsyCoder OK I've tried this also but getting the same error. How would I do what I'm trying to achieve? Maybe with a BSON document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79668/discussion-between-gypsycoder-and-tripvoltage).

Comment: @gypsyCoder can you shed anymore light on this problem?

Comment: actually, your problem is not in the syntax, it is about the process you are trying

Comment: @gypsyCoder my json is in json files and I want to be able to add multiple files to the db?